# How to use basic auth with axios nuxt module

Tags: javascript, axios, nuxt.js, basic-authentication

I am currently struggling with Nuxt's Axios module: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/.
I would like to get some data from a specific endpoint where I have to use Basic Authentication.

Normally, with Axios, I would do something like:

```js
await axios.get(
  'http://endpoint',
  {},
  {
    withCredentials: true,
    auth: {
      username: 'userame',
      password: 'pw'
    }
  }
)
```

Unfortunately, with Nuxt's Axios module, it seems it is not that easy...
I tried something like:

```js
const data = await this.$axios.$get(
  'http://endpoint',
  {},
  {
    credentials: true,
    auth: {
      username: 'user',
      password: 'pw'
    }
  }
)
```

But that leaves me with a `401 Unauthorized`...

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is it a typo or in your nuxt axios call you use`credentials:true` instead of `withCredentials:true`?

Comment: No that is (weirdly) how you have to write it with the nuxt module (https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options.html#credentials). this will set `withCredentials`. ‍♂️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to [`axios.get()`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config-1) (and `$axios.$get()`) is the **Axios config**, but you've passed it as the third argument (which is effectively ignored). The API likely omits the data argument from `axios.get()` because data doesn't apply in this context.

The solution is to replace the 2nd argument with your config:

```js
const data = await this.$axios.$get(
  'http://endpoint',
  // {},          // <-- Remove this! 2nd argument is for config
  {
    credentials: true,
    auth: {
      username: 'user',
      password: 'pw'
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had it like this in the beginning, but read somewhere, that the second argument (config) has to be passed and that auth was not part of that config. That is very likely to be a mistake though. Anyway I went back to the code you suggested, but still I would get a 401... 
I now would like to eliminate the chances that I was provided with a wrong pw/user or that the backend has another problem. I will try to find a basic auth test API,which I can use to make some dummy request to make sure my axios code is correct...

Comment: Anyway: when requesting I get this error: 401, but also blocked because of CORS. The people responsible for the backend told me that the added an `Allow Origin: *` header to allow my requests. So I am a bit confused, could it be that this is really a CORS issue?
What is your opinion?
(see image of browsers network inspector)
https://ibb.co/k8vDR87

(Oh and thanks a lot btw!)

Edit: I think it is indeed a problem with CORS, because when testing with my insomnia app, I don't see the response headers the promised...
I will keep digging....